# Spring roo installation

Tags: linux, spring-roo

Spring roo seems a convenient tool and I have a chance to try it. I created a linux package so that I can maintain it using the package manager to install or uninstall or share it in my team. The package manager will install the spring-roo to the /opt/spring-roo directory. But when running the roo command it will create a cache directory in the $ROO_HOME(/opt/spring-roo) and generates many small bundle files. But a normal user doesn't have the write access to the /opt/spring-roo. So my question is: is there a way to use another path as a cache directory just like the $HOME/.cache/roo? I noted that there is a config.properties in the $ROO_HOME but I can't figure a way to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

After researching the roo.sh I found I can set the cache dir directly from the roo.sh. So I change it to the user's home, just like`ROO_OSGI_FRAMEWORK_STORAGE="$HOME/.cache/spring-roo"`.